# Segue to another storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I dont know how create segue from storyboard 2 to storyboard 3(image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLhJY.png). Afterwards user tap save button(storyboard 2), i need save item and open saved item on storyboard 3. I try use Unwind Segue, but this doesnt work.

I try use instantiateViewController. I set on storyboard 3 Storyboard ID("Item") and then add this code to save button:

```
    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Item") as! ItemViewController
    self.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

But when Storyboard 3 open, after tap Save Button on Storyboard2, navigationbar on Storyboard 3 doesnt showed. Anyone can help find me solution to this problem?

Comment: btw they're not storyboards but `UIViewControllers`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which storyboard you want to use exactly along with your `ViewController` identifier.

Try this:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YOUR_OTHER_STORYBOARD_NAME", bundle: nil)
let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Item") as! ItemViewController
self.show(viewController, sender: self)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer,@cedan-misquith, but its doesnt work. Maybe second string should be:

`let viewController = STORYBOARD.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Item") as! ItemViewController`

?

Comment: @artemijeverzilovjr96 Ok try this,
After clicking save on `viewcontroller2` just pop back to `viewcontroller1` and then push to `viewcontroller3` with the data you want to show there.